# May one count the Omer if he has texted someone which night it is?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer

We are careful to say "Yesterday was 8" etc to ensure that we do not inadvertently count the Omer before we say the bracha. However, what if one texted "Tonight is 9" to someone? Does this count as "counting"?

Comment: I would assume that you can still count with a bracha, but as a side note, from day seven and on, you can still count with a bracha as long as you haven't said the "which is one week and 2 days" part of the phrase.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! It had been asked before so got closed quickly but hopefully you got the answer you wanted. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!